# How to make a prediction if training time series have different lengths?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, predictive-models

**Description**: I have 100 products. For each item I have the number of hours it has been used for each quarter of multiple years.

| Item | 2020_Q1 | 2020_Q2 | 2020_Q3 | 2020_Q4 | 2021_Q1 | 2021_Q2 | 2021_Q3 | 2021_Q4 | Sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 50 | 80 | 75 | 90 | 60 | 70 | 85 | 95 | No |
| B | 30 | 50 | 45 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | Yes |
| C | 70 | 85 | 80 | 90 | 75 | 80 | 90 | 100 | No |
| D | 20 | 70 | 40 | 45 | 30 | NaN | NaN | NaN | Yes |
| E | 60 | 75 | 70 | 80 | 55 | 45 | 40 | 30 | Yes |

If the item has been used less or equal to 50 hours in three consecutive quarters, the item is sold.

**Question**: Would you be able to suggest a smart and elegant way to predict if an item will be sold in the next quarter (2022_Q1) if a new time series is passed as an input?

**Note**: I would be able to achieve my goal if the series had the same the same lengths but in this case I am totally lost.